# Mysql/PHP PDO statement failing with wildcard

Tags: php, mysql

```
$pdo = $db_con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE Age=:Age AND ClientID=:ClientID AND LastName=:LastName"); 
$pdo->bindValue(':Age', $_SESSION['Age']);
$pdo->bindValue(':ClientID', $ID);
$pdo->bindValue(':LastName', $Last_Name."%");
$pdo->execute();
```

Adding the wildcard after $Last_Name is causing the statement to produce no results.

If the value for $Last_Name is Smith that produces a results but only if the wildcard is not there. I have tried the wildcards on both sides and the same thing happens.

No errors are generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're not using a `LIKE` comparison. Wildcards only apply when using `LIKE`. Since you're doing an equality test (`=`), you're literally requiring that a `%` be present in the matched data.

Try

```
SELECT .... AND LastName LIKE :LastName
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use LIKE:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE Age=:Age AND ClientID=:ClientID AND LastName LIKE :LastName
```